# Change a enumerated list to horizontal with Tasks

Tags: horizontal-alignment, enumerate, itemize, tasks

I have spesicif list I need to change into a horizontal alignment. I thought of using the tasks package, but can not figure out how to do it. Here is the list:

```
\documentclass[12pt,numbers=noenddot,headings=small,parskip=half,headsepline, listof=nochaptergap, listof=totoc,index=totoc]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\usepackage[a4paper, includehead, left=3.5cm, right=1.7cm, top=2.5cm, bottom=2.0cm]{geometry}

\setlength{\parindent}{0em}
\usepackage{enumitem,tasks}
\usepackage{multicol}

\begin{document}

\begin{multicols}{2}
\setlist[itemize]{wide =0pt, leftmargin=*, nosep,before=\KOMAoptions{parskip=false}}
\begin{enumerate}[topsep=0pt,itemsep=-1ex,partopsep=1ex,parsep=3.5ex,leftmargin=*]
\item Item 
 \begin{itemize}
    \item Item
\end{itemize}
\item Item
 \begin{itemize}
    \item Item
\end{itemize}
\item Item
 \begin{itemize}
    \item Item
    \item Item
\end{itemize}
\item Item
 \begin{itemize}[wide=0pt]
    \item Item
Intertext
    \item Item
\end{itemize}
\item Item
\end{enumerate}
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's how to do it:

```
\documentclass[12pt,numbers=noenddot,headings=small,parskip=half,headsepline, listof=nochaptergap, listof=totoc,index=totoc]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\usepackage[a4paper, includehead, left=3.5cm, right=1.7cm, top=2.5cm, bottom=2.0cm, showframe]{geometry}

\setlength{\parindent}{0em}
\usepackage{enumitem,tasks}
\usepackage{multicol}

\begin{document}

\setlist[itemize]{wide =0pt, leftmargin=*, nosep, before=\KOMAoptions{parskip=false}, after =\vspace*{-\baselineskip}}
\settasks{counter-format=tsk[1]. , item-indent = 1.2em, label-width =1.2em, label-offset = 0em, after-item-skip = -1ex}
\begin{tasks}(2)
  \task Item
  \begin{itemize}
    \item Item
  \end{itemize}
  \task Item
  \begin{itemize}
    \item Item
  \end{itemize}
  \task Item
  \begin{itemize}
    \item Item
    \item Item
  \end{itemize}
  \task Item
  \begin{itemize}[wide=0pt]
    \item Item
          Intertext
    \item Item
  \end{itemize}
  \task Item
\end{tasks}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Perfect, thank you. How can I change the spacing below the last bullet point item to the next task?

Comment: It's the `after-item-task` key. I had to set it to  negative value (default: 1ex plus 1ex minus 1ex) probably because of the nested itemize. A description of all the keys is to be found in the documentation, §4, pp. 8-9.