# How to make two columns write horizontally instead of vertically?

Tags: itemize, multicol, multicolumn

I want to make two columns with items, for example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage{multicol}

\begin{document}
\section{First Section}
\begin{multicols}{2}
\begin{itemize}
    \item Item 1
    \item Item 2
    \item Item 3
    \item Item 4
\end{itemize}
\end{multicols}

\end{document}
```

This will of course, display like this:

[image]

Instead, I want it to automatically write the first one on the left and then the one on the right; then the second one on the left, and so on. Like this:

[image]

I had to do that manually by changing the order of the items; is there a way to automate this?

Comment: Related/duplicate: [Change a enumerated list to horizontal with Tasks](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/383912/5764)

Comment: @Werner thanks
Someone close the question